# Attachment : Triggered Send using REST API

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I need to attach pdf from my Apex code (Salesforce) Using REST API ExactTarget.

This PDF is Unique to each email.

Please share your ideas on to this

I am trying to use 
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#AttachFile

and 
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_attachments/

First Question is how can i find if attachment feature is enabled for my org or not
Thanks,
Pravin

Comment: You would need to contact support or your account rep for this one.  Not really any way to check in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A profile attribute could be used to hold the value for the location of the unique location for that subscribers PDF.  This profile attribute would need to be created in the UI in the Profile Management section. Lets assume the field is called PDFLocation.  The body of the email would have to contain a reference to the AttachFile function referencing that attribute:

```
%%=Attachfile("HTTP", PDFLocation)=%%
```

Then in the JSON body for ContactAttributes, pass the value:

```
{
    "From": {
        "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "Code@"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "example@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "PDFLocation": "http://www.exampledomain.com/somefile.pdf"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mac. I implemented this. but later i realized my org is not enabled with this feature. Next Steps are to get it enabled as its found as chargeable feature